# How to access methods from a sub controller without - from the beginning - knowing which sub controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, subclass

My custom method `webshops#reset` is never actually called from the `webshops_controller`, because it no `Webshop` objects exists. Instead I have subclasses like `PrestashopWebshop`, `MagentoWebshop`, etc.

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do

  ...

  resources :webshops
  resources :magento_webshops
  resources :prestashop_webshops

  get "api/webshop/:id/reset" => "webshops#reset"

  ...

end
```

Here are the methods from the sub class controller.

```
class MagentoWebshopsController < WebshopsController

  def scoped_webshops
    "magento_webshops"
  end
end
```

When I from a sub class controller like `magento_webshops_controller` call the `index` action I get access to `scoped_webshops`. But when I call the custom method `reset` I can't access these sub class methods.

```
class WebshopsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :html, :json
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @webshops = current_user.send(scoped_webshops)
  end

  def reset
    webshop = Webshop.find(params[:id])
    @webshops = current_user.send(scoped_webshops)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {

      ...

      }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

So, how do I call `api/webshop/:id/reset` (all sub classes are using the same `webshops.js.coffee` to call `reset` through ajax)? I guess the whole problem is caused by `webshops_controller` working directly without having its actions called from a sub class. However, the first line (`webshop = Webshop.find(params[:id])`) should somehow make us able to determine which subclass should be used, because it returns a sub class object...

Update:

Here is the server response:

```
Started GET "/api/webshop/522ede3983c336b7d600000f/reset?time_string=5&_=1378809004554" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-10 12:30:14 +0200
Processing by WebshopsController#reset as JS
  Parameters: {"time_string"=>"5", "_"=>"1378809004554", "id"=>"522ede3983c336b7d600000f"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=feedbackzilla_development collection=webshops selector={"_id"=>"522ede3983c336b7d600000f"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4311ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=feedbackzilla_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"_id"=>"522887dc83c3368361000964"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.5710ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=feedbackzilla_development collection=webshops selector={"_id"=>"522ede3983c336b7d600000f"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4909ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=feedbackzilla_development collection=webshops selector={"_id"=>"522ede3983c336b7d600000f"} update={"$set"=>{"rebuild_days"=>5, "updated_at"=>2013-09-10 10:30:14 UTC}} flags=[] (0.1259ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms

NameError - undefined local variable or method `scoped_webshops' for #<WebshopsController:0x007fb710accc08>:
  app/controllers/webshops_controller.rb:50:in `reset'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
class WebshopsController < InheritedResources::Base
  custom_actions :resource => :reset
```

From the [inherited_resources docs](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources):

> Since version 1.2, Inherited Resources allows you to define custom
>   actions in controller:
>
> ```
> class ButtonsController < InheritedResources::Base
>   custom_actions :resource => :delete, :collection => :search
> end
> ```
>
> This code creates
>   delete and search actions in controller (they behaves like show and
>   index actions accordingly). Also, it will produce `delete_resource_{path,url}` 
>   and `search_resources_{path,url}` url helpers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this is it. I think this has something to do with moving out of the sub class scope, so the `webshops_controller` takes over without recognizing a sub class. This is supposibly caused by the call being made from client side `webshops.js.coffee` to `api/webshop/:id/reset` instead of e.g. `api/magento_webshop/:id/reset`